# Can someone please explain what (e) is doing and as well as the target object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I pretty new to Jquery/JavaScript and was wondering if someone could please explain exactly what (e) is doing? Is this similar to the "this" object?

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testDiv').on('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    $clicked.css('background', 'red');
  });
});
```

Comment: `e` is used for `event`.

Comment: e is tied to the event context so in this case 'click', e.target will be the element that was clicked.

Comment: `e` is the name of the parameter of the event handler, which gets passed an [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e` parameter contains the `Event Object`, passed to your event Handler function.
Inside the event object you'll find relevant data relative to the triggered event.

From MDN Web docs:

> DOM Events are sent to notify code of interesting things that have
>   taken place. Each event is represented by an object which is based on
>   the Event interface, and may have additional custom fields and/or
>   functions used to get additional information about what happened.
>   Events can represent everything from basic user interactions to
>   automated notifications of things happening in the rendering model.

**If we are talking about a `click` event, for exampke, `e.target` would be a reference to the  DOM Element wich received the click. Wich corresponds in this case with the value of `this`, inside the handler scope**

---

You can find more information about Events here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: So, it doesn't act as $(this). Because we specified which id we target. Which is in this case #testDiv. Is this then in a way like "return"?

Comment: @CazadorShaw in this case it is the same of `this`, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/npuo9ouv/

Comment: I think I'm understanding this a little better. it's just hard to wrap my head around this as a first time programmer. Thanks!